# How does Swift decide which function to execute if functions are alike?

Tags: swift

Like the two function below, which function will Swift execute first?

Is there a pattern of it?

Because I encountered two more complex functions than this. It executes the "Any" one first, no matter what the order I make to them (cause I assume it execute from the memory address but it seems not).

Some say that it will execute the "Any" one (in my other case) due to its wider range of struct or class. But the example below says the opposite.

Wondering why and how this happen or where I can get the answer.

```
import UIKit

func add(_ x: Int,_ y: Any) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func add(_ a: Int,_ b: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

print(add(2, 3))
// "1\n"

print(add(2, "3"))
// "3\n"
```

here is my other case:

```
let constraint = titleLabel.layout(.width, .lessThanOrEqual, 122)
```

this is what I expect to be execute:

```
func layout(_ attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, _ relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation, _ constant: CGFloat, active: Bool = true, priority: UILayoutPriority = .init(1000)) -> NSLayoutConstraint {}
```

but it actually execute this one:

```
func layout(_ attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, _ relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation, _ toItem: Any?, active: Bool = true, priority: UILayoutPriority = .init(1000)) -> NSLayoutConstraint {}
```

if swift chooses the most specific one, shouldn't it execute the "Float" one?

Comment: The “most specific” matching function is called. Which result did you expect?

Comment: By the way, these are called "overload resolution rules". There doesn't seem to be any spec that explains them, but you could look into `ConstraintSolver.cpp` of the Swift compiler, to see the implementation for yourself

Comment: BTW - All of these examples demonstrate why using `_` for all argument labels is a bad idea. Too much ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift compiler chooses the function signature that matches the call you are making.

When you call `add` with two `Int` arguments, it sees that there is an `add` function with two `Int` parameters so it calls that one.

When you call `add` with an `Int` and a `String`, it first looks for such a function but there isn't one. Then it sees that there is one with `Int` and `Any`. Since `Any` can match any type, it matches. So that one is called.

There's more to it than that but that's a good enough generalization for your question.

Comment: thx for your respond, I've update my post.
how about my second situation? seems that 122 also fit the CGFloat, right?

Comment: `122` is an `Int`, not `CGFloat`, so `Any` matches. If you passed `122.0` it would be a `Double`. That might match `CGFloat` but it might match `Any`. Now if you had `let myConstant: CGFloat = 122` then passed `myConstant` then the function using `CGFloat` would be chosen over the one with `Any`.

Comment: got it. sounds very reasonable!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's being as specific as it can.

It calls add(int, int) when it can, and falls back to add(int, any) when needed.

Comment: thx for your respond, I've update my post.
for my second situation, since I put 122 when calling. 
how come the CGFloat one not been execute first?